# Unresolved reference while trying to import software.amazon.awscdk.services.logs.destinations.LambdaDestination

Tags: amazon-web-services, kotlin, gradle, aws-cdk

I'm trying to add a trigger to a Lambda with CloudWatch as source using CDK, but so far, no luck.

Relevant code:

```
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.*
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.lambda.Function
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.logs.*
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.logs.destinations.LambdaDestination
import software.amazon.awscdk.services.logs.SubscriptionFilterProps


subscriptionFilterProps = SubscriptionFilterProps
            .builder()
            .logGroup(logGroup)
            .destination(LambdaDestination(Function.fromFunctionName(lambdaName)))
            .filterPattern(FilterPattern.anyTerm("CreateSecret", "PutSecret"))
            .build()
```

I'm getting three errors:

```
Unresolved reference: destinations
Unresolved reference: LambdaDestination
Unresolved reference: fromFunctionName
```

I guess the main issue is the first one, and the others are just a consequence.

In `build.gradle.kts` I have both

```
   implementation("software.amazon.awscdk:lambda:${cdkVersion}")
   implementation("software.amazon.awscdk:logs:${cdkVersion}")
```

Any idea why it's failing?

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was a misinterpretation of the CDK documentation, and the actual package to add to the implementation is `software.amazon.awscdk:logs-destinations` like in other languages.